# Calc and mathtools : issue

Tags: mathtools, titletoc, calc

I have an issue when using `titlesec` with `mathttools` :

```
l.19 \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}                          
! Undefined control sequence.
```

Here is an minimal example :

Can somenone help me ?

Thank you

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%compilation XeLaTeX
\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
%
%compilation LaTeX
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\newpage

\chapter{A chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum
\newpage
\chapter{Second chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

**EDIT : Second minimal example**

**At second compilation, it doesn't work.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%compilation XeLaTeX
\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
%
%compilation LaTeX
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\newpage

\chapter{A chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum
\newpage
\chapter{Second chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should protect the \setcounter: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `mathtools` per se, but rather the fact that `mathtools` loads the `calc` package. In any case U;riks solution is the proper one, some macros needs protection in certain circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I try `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}` it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I've added a new complete example which doesn't compile.

Comment: The `article` class doesn't define `\chapter`. Try with `\documentclass{book}` or `\documentclass{report}`. If you want only chapters in the main table of contents you need to set the `tocdepth` counter to `0`, not `1`.